# Generate "scattered" items, that do not overlap

Tags: python, collision-detection, turtle-graphics

This is a question that i had to solve, but have been banging my head against a wall for the past 5 days. There must be something really simple that i am missing, or misunderstanding, as the logic seems 100% correct in my head, but it just won't work.

I need to draw "scattered" houses, that do not over lap, 100 of them.
I have to use turtle to draw them, so i have X and Y coordinates. 
And X and Y list for verification purposes, to see if a house is already in that place.

What i am doing is drawing a "house" (square with a triangle on top)  on the randomized coordinates, 
I loop while the number of houses is less than 100.
On each loop i randomize the x and y coordinates, from where i start drawing each house with turtle.
I check if the value is already in the X and Y verification lists, and also if my new X and Y are +/- the size of the house (treating it as a square)

```
import turtle
import time
import random
t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.screensize(1920,1000)
x_verif = []
y_verif = []
t.speed(0)
collision = None


def square():
    for s in range(0, 4):
        t.forward(90)
        t.left(90)

def triangle():
    for s in range(0, 2):
        t.left(-60)
        t.forward(52)

def house():
    square()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(90)
    triangle()

def scatter():
    print("a")
    house()
    x1 = random.randint(-850, 850)
    y1 = random.randint(-380, 380)
    count = 0
    while count < 100:
        print("a2")
        i = 0
        u = 0
        collision = False
        for  tries in range (0, 2):
            print("a3")
            x_verif.append(x1)
            y_verif.append(y1)
        while u < 100:
            print("a4")

            print(x_verif, y_verif, x1, y1)
            while i < len(x_verif):
                x1 = random.randint(-850, 850)
                y1 = random.randint(-380, 380)
                print(x1, y1)
                if x1 not in x_verif and (x1 > x_verif[i]+91 or x1 < x_verif[i]-91):
                    if y1 not in y_verif and (y1 > y_verif[i]+142 or y1 < y_verif[i]-142):
                        collision = False
                else:
                    collision = True
            if collision == False:
                            t.penup()
                            t.hideturtle()
                            t.setx(x1)
                            t.sety(y1)
                            t.pendown()
                            house()
                            x_verif.append(x1)
                            y_verif.append(y1)
                            count += 1
                i+= 1
        u += 1


scatter()
```

Sorry for the ugly code, and the simplicity behind it. I would love to use list comprehensions for this, but i do not know where my logic fails at the moment. This is like my 100th try, as of this version it only draws the initial house and i think it loops infinitely somewhere....

My problem lies in looping through the whole lists for every new value. Do i need to loop through them every time, or is there some IF condition that I can use?  Edit: It keeps on looping through random values, but none of them are accepted by the two IF statements that i'm using.

On a side note: With my current code they also change direction of drawing every time... No idea why is that happening....

Edit: I am very thankful for all the solutions! I'm struggling with the note at the beginning of the question. It says that it should only take a couple more lines to do the last one, compared to the first one..... Are they joking? [image: questions]

Comment: The shown code isn't properly indented and won't even start.

Comment: That's the first thing i did, i got shot down in the lab instantly, i would've finished in the 2h we had to do it :D

Comment: @Michael Butscher I will include the whole code that works for me, it's just that i didn't want it to get too long, check it now.

Comment: One problem is that the loop `while i < len(x_verif)` won't end because i isn't changed in the loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Is it not? What about the i += 1, that is the line just before the last one in the scatter() function?

Comment: The indentation controls where a code block starts and ends (like the while-loop). The change of i was after that block, not in it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher For some reason i believed that was in it.... i'm blind. and yeah it should be i not count....
Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a trickier problem than I assumed from the description.  My approach was to treat, and store, a house as two polygons, a square and a triangle.  I randomly test draw (pen up) a house and compare all the points in its polygons to see if they are inside existing house polygons, and vice versa.  If no overlap, draw the house for real.  The solution is *not* efficient, but it allows tight packing of houses than a simple diameter-based approach.

The [point in triangle routine](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-triangle-or-not/) is based on one from [GeeksForGeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org)

I have one slight fudge factor in my code that still needs to be polished out.  But overall it seems to achieve the objective:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

HOUSES = 100
HOUSE_SIZE = 90

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1920, 1000

# assumes roof is an isosceles triangle
ROOF_SIDE = HOUSE_SIZE * 3**0.5 / 3
ROOF_HEIGHT = ROOF_SIDE // 2

FONT_SIZE = HOUSE_SIZE // 3
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

def square(turtle, identity=None):
    turtle.begin_poly()

    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(HOUSE_SIZE)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.end_poly()

    turtle.forward(HOUSE_SIZE/2 - FONT_SIZE/2)  # visually finish square

    if identity:  # label each house with a number
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(HOUSE_SIZE/2)
        turtle.write(identity, align='center', font=FONT)
        turtle.backward(HOUSE_SIZE/2)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.pendown()

    turtle.forward(HOUSE_SIZE/2 + FONT_SIZE/2)  # visually finish square
    turtle.right(90)  # return to original orientation

    return turtle.get_poly()

def triangle(turtle):
    turtle.begin_poly()

    turtle.forward(HOUSE_SIZE)
    turtle.left(150)
    turtle.forward(ROOF_SIDE)

    turtle.end_poly()

    turtle.left(60)
    turtle.forward(ROOF_SIDE)  # visually finish triangle
    turtle.right(210)  # return to original orientation

    return turtle.get_poly()

def house(turtle, identity=None):
    return (square(turtle, identity), triangle(turtle))

def area_of_triangle(p1, p2, p3):

    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    x3, y3 = p3

    return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2))) // 2

def is_inside_triangle(point, triangle):

    p1, p2, p3 = triangle

    a = area_of_triangle(p1, p2, p3)

    b = area_of_triangle(point, p2, p3)
    c = area_of_triangle(p1, point, p3)
    d = area_of_triangle(p1, p2, point)

    return abs(a - (b + c + d)) < 5  # 5 == fudge factor, sigh

def is_inside_square(point, square):

    x, y = point

    p1, p2, p3, p4 = square

    _, y1 = p1
    x2, _ = p2
    _, y3 = p3
    x4, _ = p4

    return x4 <= x <= x2 and y3 <= y <= y1

def scatter(turtle):
    houses = []
    count = 0

    while count < HOUSES:

        x = randint(-WINDOW_WIDTH/2, WINDOW_WIDTH/2 - HOUSE_SIZE)
        y = randint(HOUSE_SIZE - WINDOW_HEIGHT/2, WINDOW_HEIGHT/2 - ROOF_HEIGHT)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        proposed_square, proposed_triangle = house(turtle)  # test draw invisible house
        turtle.pendown()

        collision = False

        for point in proposed_square + proposed_triangle:  # does proposed house collide with houses?
            for square, triangle in houses:
                if is_inside_square(point, square) or is_inside_triangle(point, triangle):
                    collision = True
                    break

            if collision:
                break

        for square, triangle in houses:  # do houses collide with proposed house?
            for point in square + triangle:
                if is_inside_square(point, proposed_square) or is_inside_triangle(point, proposed_triangle):
                    collision = True
                    break

            if collision:
                break

        if not collision:
            count += 1
            houses.append(house(turtle, identity=count))  # actually draw new house
            print(count)

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

scatter(turtle)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

This problem is simplified somewhat by the consistent orientation of houses.  If the houses were randomly oriented, compass-wise, the square overlap calculations would be more complex.

The solution could be made more efficient by doing triangle overlap with triangle, square overlap with triangle, etc. tests instead of simply "point inside".  We could also push the collision logic down into the `square()` and `triangle()` routines to throw an error as soon as there's a collsion, rather than completing a house and then testing.

Given the size of the screen area, size of a house, the number of houses, and the random scattering, I believe it may be possible for an idividual run of the program to stall trying to place a house where there may not be available space:

[image]

Comment: Holy moly. That is a bit complicated and i'm sure my lab tutor will not be happy if i turned up with polygon detection. Though i am happy you showed me something i've never heard of before and that i'll learn! It'll probably take me a couple of days to understand it completely but again, thank you so much!
And yeah a couple of times, especially the last 3 houses, always take a bit longer to draw, never have i ever brought it to a stall though.

Answer (score 1):

Defo no the best way to do it but

```
import turtle
import time
import random
t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.screensize(1920,1000)
x_verif = []
y_verif = []
t.speed(0)
collision = None


def square():
    for s in range(0, 4):
        t.forward(90)
        t.left(90)

def triangle():
    for s in range(0, 2):
        t.left(-60)
        t.forward(52)

def house():
    square()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(90)
    triangle()
    t.left(30) #returning to 90 degrres
def scatter():
    beenAt = [] #this will hold every place that there is a house
    for i in range(100): 
        t.penup()
        loop = True
        while loop == True:
            area = random.randint(-850, 850) 
            for i in range(91): #looping for the size of the house
                if area+i in beenAt: #if the number chosen plus i is in beenAt stop because we cant use that place
                    break
                if i == 90: #if at the finial part of our loop then draw house
                    t.goto(area, 0)
                    t.pendown()
                    for i in range(area, area + 91): 
                        beenAt.append(i) #add to been at list every place we have drawn
                    house()
                    loop = False
scatter()
```

Comment: Thank you, I just need to understand how this is working, and modify it so it can actually serve my purpose :D
Edit: Ohhhh so instead of looping through each list index you actually loop through all the values for X and check if each one of them is in the list. Right. That's an idea  i hadn't thought of.
I just need to do the same thing for Y

Comment: I hope this helps if not just tell me.

Comment: yeah this defo isn't the best way of doing but TBH cba to an proper collision detection.

Comment: No, it's fine! It's still a solution, and it works, unlike mine :D Ahhh If i don't manage to draw 100 houses when I add the use of Y too (or i screw smth up that i cannot figure out) I will probably contact you again :D Thank you!
I'm still on the lookout for the collision detection version for this problem :D

Comment: Do you actually need to append EACH number of the length of the house                  ```for i in range(area, area + 91):
                        beenAt.append(i) to the list. Would it still not work, since we're checking for each value anyway?

Comment: @YeYeeeeee Ok sure. I can right you a full collision detection if you want as it would just be changing how it writes and reads from the list.

Comment: Oh I mean it'd be cool if you did it. I was just saying it so that if somebody wanted to do it, they didn't think my question was closed :D I don't want to abuse your help, stranger ^_^

Comment: Oh true you need to append each of them.